# NAICS and SIC database by address/parcel number?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data

I have a large amount of addresses that I need to manually input each and every one of their building uses. There are well over a dozen of categories to choose from.

What kinds of databases should I turn to in order to expedite this process and is this publicly available information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My company purchases SIC and other data that is associated with our customer addresses each year. DatabaseUSA, Nielsen, InfoUSA, and Dunn and Bradstreet are a few companies that sell those data (dozens more ; just Google). What you do is give them a list of addresses (and optionally a name) and they match data to them. There are inexpensive providers as well, but I've found that their data is poor quality and/or outdated. What you pay for is a scrubbing process. You can also go the parcel geocode route if the parcels you have have landuse info attached.

Comment: It is precisely that sort of data I am looking for... Geocoded parcels with landuse info attached. It seems Google might be the only company that actually has accurate, up to date information. Furthermore they fiercely safeguard it from all potential extraction which is understandable. Purchasing the data is not yet an option for me although it may be in the future. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Google still consumes a lot of data from third parties. At least Digital Map Products has decent standardized landuse info attached to their parcels (accuracy ultimately depends on what the county itself sets landuse as, which is often set for empty lots). I'm sure CoreLogic does too. Look around but expect to pay hundreds of dollars per county at least for good parcel data from a third party. If all you need are a few counties and you can work with the actual county, then you might get lucky; some counties give away their data or only charge a nominal fee.